# Multimodal data - where does one tail end and the other begin?

Tags: r, quantiles, mixture-distribution, mode

I have some observed (i.e., not generated by any hypothesized distribution, but generated by real processes) data that I believe is bi-modal (it may have more modes than two).

In this dataset, there are 241,792 observations. The deciles are the following values:

```
MIN  - 0.1472
10th - 0.3072
20th - 0.4094
30th - 0.6267
40th - 0.9396
50th - 1.4678
60th - 2.4125
70th - 4.2814
80th - 7.8145
90th - 16.7443
MAX - 241.0211
```

How can I identify modes using R?

Once identified and assuming that each mode is the location of central tendency for a local, somewhat Gaussian distribution, how should I determine where one tail ends and the next begins?

The end result is that I'm trying to treat the set of data as the composition of partitions, where each partition can be analyzed on its own.

Comment: The tails overlap, and extend to $\pm\infty$ if Gaussian

Comment: In theory, sure. In practice, I'm just looking for cut points between the distributions.

Comment: "Cut points" don't exist. But see the [mixtools package](http://exploringdatablog.blogspot.com/2011/08/fitting-mixture-distributions-with-r.html)

Answer (score 2):

First, it looks highly unlikely the data is the result of any number of Gaussian distributions, with all the data being suspiciously positive and the median so much further from the maximum than the minimum.  So I would look elsewhere for likely distributions.

Second, why not try visual methods first - a density line plot should show straight away if there are obviously two modes (ie they will be the two local maxima).

Finally, as Abe says, it's important to note that if it is a mixed distribution the tails overlap, so at most you're looking for a point where an observation is more likely to be from distribution A than from B.  To determine this you need to identify the two distributions and estimate them.  There's several ways of going about this, but I'd like to see the evidence they're needed first.

Comment: I will try some visual methods, but don't agree with the statement "the median so much further from the maximum than the minimum" as reason that the "super" distribution is not the result of "sub" Gaussian distributions. This could be the case if one of the "sub" distributions (admittedly, assuming they exist) with high density is close to the minimum.